# Conditional statement to change specific value

Tags: r, data-cleaning

How does one write code in R such that: IF the value for the variable "variable" was 1 AND the value for the variable "othervariable" is 1, THEN the value for "othervariable" becomes "NA" rather than the original entry of 1?

So, in this case, a lot of values under "othervariable" are 1, and they are correct and should not change. I only want to remove the value of 1 when a given participants' answer to the previous question was also 1.

Comment: I think this is covered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190063/r-replace-variable-given-multiple-conditions - let me know if your issue has extra detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could try base R:

```
othervariable<-ifelse(variable==1 & othervariable==1, NA, othervariable)
```

Or dplyr:

```
yourdataframe%>%mutate(othervariable=ifelse(variable==1 & othervariable==1, NA, othervariable)
```

But answers to this question are all over SO